# How to validate PHP Form input and database submittion

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

Am just getting my hand on php and I need some little help please. I am working on a registration form with server-side validation, then after validation, the form input should be submitted to the database. I entered data, click submit button, but the data were not submitted to the database. There is no error message. I like you to help me point out where have been wrong and give me a possible solution. Thanks.

Index.php

```
<?php
include ('signup.php');
?>
<div class="maindiv">
<div class="login"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="pageintro">
<p>PHP</p>
<p>PROJECT 1</p>
</div>
<div class="regform">
<form name="reg" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >
<p class="regformp">Fill all Fields</p>
<div class="regwrap">
<div class="inp">Full Name</div>
<div class="inp1"><input type="text" name="FullName" value="<?php echo $FullName; ?>"></div>
<span class="error"><?php echo $fullnameErr;?></span>
<div class="inp">E-Mail</div>
<div class="inp1"><input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>"></div>
<span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<div class="inp">Password</div>
<div class="inp1"><input type="password" name="Password"></div>
<span class="error"><?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
<div class="inp">Confirm Password</div>
<div class="inp1"><input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword"></div>
<span class="error"><?php echo $conpasswordErr;?></span>
<div class="inp">Gender</div>
<div class="inp1"><input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" <?php if(isset($Gender)&& $Gender=="Male") echo "checked"; ?> >Male &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="Gender" <?php if(isset($Gender)&& $Gender=="Female") echo "checked"; ?>  Value="Female">Female</div>
<span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
<div class="inp">Date Of Birth</div>
<div class="inp1"><select name="DayOfBirth"><option>01</option>
<option>02</option>
<option>03</option>
<option>04</option>
<option>05</option></select> &nbsp; <select name="MonthOfBirth"><option>Jan</option>
<option>Feb</option>
<option>Mar</option>
<option>Apr</option>
<option>May</option></select> &nbsp; <select name="YearOfBirth"><option>1970</option>
<option>1971</option>
<option>1972</option>
<option>1973</option>
<option>1974</option></select></div>
<span class="error"><?php echo $dobErr;?></span>
<span class="error"><?php echo $mobErr;?></span>
<span class="error"><?php echo $yobErr;?></span>
<div class="inp2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP"></div></div>
</form>
```

signup.php

```
<?php
include ('project1db.php');
//Define variables
$fullnameErr="";
$emailErr="";
$passwordErr="";
$conpasswordErr="";
$genderErr="";
$dobErr="";
$mobErr="";
$yobErr="";
$FullName="";
$Email="";
$Password="";
$ConfirmPassword="";
$Gender="";
$DayOfBirth="";
$MonthOfBirth="";
$YearOfBirth="";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

if(empty($_POST["FullName"])){
$fullnameErr = "Name is required";
}
else{
$FullName = test_input($_POST["FullName"]);
//Check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$FullName)){
$fullnameErr = "Enter Valid name please!";
}
}

if(empty($_POST["Email"])){
$emailErr = "Email is required";
}else{
$EMail = test_input($_POST["Email"]);
//Check if e-mail address is correct
if(!filter_var($EMail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
$emailErr = "Invalid email address";
}
}

if(empty($_POST["Password"])){
$passwordErr = "Password is required";
}else{
$Password = test_input($_POST["Password"]);
//Check password
if(!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]{6,}$/",$Password)){
$passwordErr = "Password should contain 6+ characters, lowercase and numbers!";
}
}

if(empty($_POST["ConfirmPassword"])){
$conpasswordErr = "Confirm your Password!";
}
else{
$ConfirmPassword = test_input($_POST["ConfirmPassword"]);
//Confirm if password match
if($ConfirmPassword != $Password){
$conpasswordErr = "Password not match!";
}
}

if(empty($_POST["Gender"])){
$genderErr = "Select your Gender!";
}else{
$Gender = test_input($_POST["Gender"]);
}

if(empty($_POST["DayOfBirth"])){
$dobErr = "Select your Day Of Birth";
}else{
$DayOfBirth = test_input($_POST["DayOfBirth"]);
}
if(empty($_POST["MonthOfBirth"])){
$mobErr = "Select your Month Of Birth";
}else{
$MonthOfBirth = test_input($_POST["MonthOfBirth"]);
}

if(empty($_POST["YearOfBirth"])){
$yobErr = "Select your Year Of Birth";
}else{
$YearOfBirth = test_input($_POST["YearOfBirth"]);
}
}

function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
if($fullnameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $conpasswordErr = $genderErr = $dobErr = $mobErr = $yobErr = ""){

    $sql = "INSERT into usersignup (FullName, Email, Password, Gender, DayOfBirth, MonthOfBirth, YearOfBirth) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){

    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters

    $stmt->bind_param("ssssisi", $FullName, $Email, $Password, $Gender, $DayOfBirth, $MonthOfBirth, $YearOfBirth);



    /* Set the parameters values and execute

    the statement again to insert another row */

    $FullName = $_REQUEST['FullName'];
    $Email = $_REQUEST['Email'];
    $Password = $_REQUEST['Password'];
    $Gender = $_REQUEST['Gender'];
    $DayOfBirth = $_REQUEST['DayOfBirth'];
    $MonthOfBirth = $_REQUEST['MonthOfBirth'];
    $YearOfBirth = $_REQUEST['YearOfBirth'];

    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Records inserted successfully.";

} else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . $conn->error;

}



// Close statement

$stmt->close();



// Close connection

$conn->close();
        }
        else{

        }


?>
```

Database Connection
project1db.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3308';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'phpproject';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(!$conn )
{
die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

Comment: place an echo statement before your insert query statement and tell me know whether you see any output or not

Comment: @zenwraight Yes i have done that now, it echo the inputed data. But I also noticed that its not validating again since I have added the query. Thanks

Comment: are you going online with this? and `mysql_error()` won't work with `mysqli_` btw. Use php's error reporting and `mysqli_error($conn)` on the queries just as you did.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Am not going online with it, is just a practice solution. I've updated my database connection file with mysqli_error.

Comment: @zenwraight    I have detected the problem and solved it. Autoincrement and conditional statement. I Appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Fred-ii-      I have detected the problem and solved it. Autoincrement and conditional statement. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Cool nice :) way to go

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem and the problem have been solved.
First problem is with the Mysql database. The **AutoIncrement colunm** precisely was not set to AutoIncrement. So, I open PhpMyadmin to alter and set the Id colunm to AutoIncrement.

**Second Problem was with the conditional statement here:**

```
if($fullnameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $conpasswordErr = $genderErr = $dobErr = $mobErr = $yobErr = "")
```

The correct line of code which later worked properly is:

```
if(empty($fullnameErr) && empty($emailErr) && empty($passwordErr) && empty($conpasswordErr) && empty($genderErr) && empty($dobErr) && empty($mobErr) && empty($yobErr))
```

This is an important information for those who got confused after they have validated the data input but didn't know how to save the data into the database table.